# Can't edit TypeScript files in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I just loaded up my solution (an ASP.NET MVC project, two TypeScript projects and a couple dozen class libraries) to do some work on it in Visual Studio 2015 Pro Update2 and found that when I open a .ts file, I'm unable to type into it. If I hit the backspace key, nothing happens, but if I drag to select text and cut it, I'm able to modify the file. If I then Undo, I can restore the text, but I'm unable to otherwise apparently modify the file.

I interestingly ran into this issue last week. After completely uninstalling Visual Studio and doing a complete reinstall, I reloaded the project only to find that this issue persisted. Looking for anything odd that might be causing this to happen, I ran across the issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8659 and found that I had a tsconfig.json in one of my projects preventing me from setting the TypeScript properties on other projects. When I looked at it, I found it was completely empty and nothing was set, so I deleted it. On a whim, I attempted to edit a TypeScript file again and functionality was restored as though nothing had happened, so I assumed this was some sort of fluke and disregarded it.

Today, I'm back in the same pickle but have no tsconfig.json files, populated or not, in the solution. I can edit the properties for each project as expected, but I can't type into any file ending in .ts. If I open an html file, I can modify it as expected. If I open a C# file, I can modify that as well, but .ts and I'm just mashing keys without any effect. Restarting VS does nothing and I know from last week that a reinstall doesn't do the trick either.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so, can you shed some light on what's causing it and how I might resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been seeing the same behavior. I was unable to edit any ts file in my Cordova/Ionic project inside Visual Studio, although editing with another editor worked fine. Changing the tsconfig.json and rebuilding seems to have solved it for now. Even after I revert the changes in tsconfig and rebuild, editing ts files keeps working. So if you don't have a tsconfig, maybe it suffices to temporarily add a minimal one.